# Zabbix: Dependency

Tags: zabbix, dependencies

I would like to monitor a service that depends on the server and a login service being up.

So I would like an alarm to go off:

- to the networking group if the server does not respond to ping
- to the server people if the login service is down
- to the application people if the service behind login is down

But I do not want to spam the app people if network is down or the server people if the application is down.

So I need a way to express dependency on alarms:

ping < login < app

How do I express these dependencies?

Comment: trigger dependency can achieve this goal. detail is at here https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/triggers/dependencies

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to configure different actions & recipients for each case you described.

So, open up **Configuration -> Actions**, and configure there something like

For network people:

- Trigger value = PROBLEM
- Trigger = (the ICMP ping trigger)
- Operations: Send message to networking group

For server people:

- Trigger value = PROBLEM
- Trigger = (your login service trigger)
- Operations: Send message to server group

For app people:

- Trigger value = PROBLEM
- Trigger = (your application trigger)
- Operations: Send message to application group

Also make sure that **type of calculation** under **Conditions** tab is set to `AND`.

I hope this helps you. :)